# Q: Gmail Api Returning Emails With InternalDates In the Future

Tags: gmail-api

I am attempting to use the Gmail api to synchronize all the email's from a user's Gmail inbox. I am using the Partial Synchronization technique described in Gmail's "Synchronizing Clients" [1] documentation. One of the listed limitations of this is that in rare cases the historyId of certain emails are unavailable. Under these circumstances, it is advised that the client fall back on using "Full Synchronization", which states that the client should "retrieve and store as many of the most recent messages or threads as are necessary for your purpose".

This all makes sense. When I have issues with Partial Synchronization, I attempt to look through an inboxes messages by time range. To do this, I effectively store a record of the `( emailAddress, historyId, internalDate )` of each email I sync and then when falling back on Full Synchronization I attempt to sync all email since the most recent `internalDate` that I have already synced.

My issue is that the cases that seem to cause partial synchronization to fail also seem to cause Full Synchronization to fail, and many of these cases are caused by emails with `internalDates` *in the future* (I can't share these examples for privacy reasons). The failure case seems to be something like the following

1. I sync email E with historyId H and an internalDate I some time in the future
2. Some time passes
3. I receive a push notification from google indicating that their are new emails to sync
4. I lookup the most recent message that I have syncecd for this inboxId, finding email E
5. I attempt a partial sync using the listHistory [2] endpoint with historyId H
6. The listHistory request fails with a 404
7. I attempt a full sync using the listMessages [3] endpoint using the query `newer_than:{hours_since-internalDate-I}`, but this request doesn't make any sense since the `internalDate` of this message is in the future.

I can imagine a few different solutions to this problem. Perhaps I should simply ignore these emails as spam, or perhaps I should store a timestamp of when I synced each email and then perform a Full Synchronization on the timestamp I have stored.

Either way, this seems like a bug in the Gmail API, as the `internalDate` should really be when Gmail received the email. I initially suspected that this might be caused by Gmail's new schedule feature and that the `internalDate` might be when the email was scheduled in the future, but I confirmed that some of the examples I have are definitely for emails that the user's inbox *received*, not *sent*. Really not sure what to make of this edge case within the `internalDate` api.

So my question is, what is the advised way to handle bogus future `internalDates`? And is it a bug?

1. https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sync
2. https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/history/list
3. https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list

Comment: What format are you sending the `{hours_since-internalDate-I}` parameter? `internalDate` is returned by `Users.messages: list` in Unix time in milliseconds. How far in the future are the internalDates, and does this happen every time you make the query for an internalDate or only sometimes?

Comment: Hey @RafaGuillermo, sorry for the slow response to this. Answers to your questions...

1. We were formatting `internalDate` as an hour. Aka `newer_than:1h`. However, using epoch seconds seems to be a much more precise solution, and I've since noticed that is supported in the api using `after:epoch_second`.

2. The example I have of an email in the future has the internalDate of 2085776896000, which is in 2036. It is an email with the INBOX label, hence why I say it is not a scheduled email.

Comment: Hey I think I found a solution to this that works. The trick is to add a defensive `before:epochSecondOfCurrentTime` search param. This prevents Gmail from returning emails with future internal dates. It still seems to be as tho the existence of emails with internal dates in 2036 is a bug, but with a simple work around this doesn't feel as pressing to me.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, at any point have you migrated mail into GMail from another client or inserted messages via the API at all? By default, when messages are migrated/inserted, or when using IMAP, GMail will look at the header of the message and then use 'dateHeader' as the value of the `internalDateSource` parameter in the query which doesn't sanitise dates if they're malformed and from the future.

Comment: Hey @RafaGuillermo what do you mean `internalDateSource`? Is that the same as `internalDate`? Further, when you say `dateHeader`, do you mean IMAP's `Date` header? 

Yes we have sent emails for this user, though the emails in question with the corrupted `internalDates` are emails this user received, not sent. We have not sent any emails on behalf of address that sent this email, but that doesn't mean the sender of that email didn't use an email client that sent an email with a Date header in the future.

Comment: [`internalDateSource`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/insert) is an optional query parameter for `Users.messages: insert` requests that allows you to tell GMail where to source the dates for email messages that you insert into the mailbox. 'dateHeader' is the string value of `internalDateSource`, and this is what tells GMail to look at the date header of message. If those headers are broken and say they're in the future then that's how GMail will read them too.

Answer (score 3):

If you're sure this is a bug, you can head to Google's Issue Tracker ([template here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191602&template=823912)) and report it so their engineering team can take a look and see what is causing this error. Alternatively if this persists with other mails or users, you can open a support ticket directly with them by going to your [admin dashboard](https://admin.google.com/) and selecting 'Contact Support' in the ? menu in the top right. This way Google can take a look into the erroneous internalDates without the need for you to post any potentially sensitive data in a public forum.

In the mean time you can workaround this dynamically by making sure that you don't fetch mails with a time in the future (psuedo-code):

```js
var now = new Date().getTime()
var q = "newer_than:1h before:" + now

GmailServiceConnect.Users.messages.list(userId = "user@domain.ext", q = q).execute()
```

But remember that Gmail uses milliseconds for Unix time not seconds so this will have to be adjusted accordingly.

Comment: "GMail uses milliseconds for Unix time not seconds" <--- THIS is what I needed!